# Get selection of vuetify list

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, vuetifyjs3

How do I get the selected item / index of from a vuetify list?

Applying `v-model` to the `<v-list>` tag does not work somehow and I can not find any working example.

I'd like to have a list of images / file names and then display the selected image. My idea was to have an `<v-img :src="imgpath">` and then `imgpath` beeing a reactive state that is changed via the list. Or is my idea completely wrong?

Minimum example of my try:

```
<template>
  <v-app>
    <v-main>
      <v-card>
        <v-list v-model='selection' :items='items'></v-list> 
        </v-card>
      <v-card class='mt-5'>
        {{ selection }}
      </v-card>
    </v-main>
  </v-app>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data: () => ({
      selection: 1,
      items: [
        { title: 'Item 0', value: 0 },
        { title: 'Item 1', value: 1 },
        { title: 'Item 2', value: 2 },
      ],
    }),
  }
</script>
```

**Expected behaviour:**
The `selection` state changes according to the selected item in the list.

**Observed behaviour:**
Visually the selection changes (a different item is marked with a gray background), but the `selection` does not change.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's super un-obvious how to do what you want, and there are no examples in the Vuetify documentation for what you'd think was a pretty common use-case.

The trick is to ignore `v-model` and instead use an `@click` event and the `:active` attribute of `v-list-item`.

Template:

```
<template>
   <v-list>
      <v-list-item v-for="item in items" 
                   :key="item.id" 
                   :active="item.id === selected"
                   @click="selected = item.id">
```

Script:

```
<script setup lang="ts">
   import { ref } from "vue";

   const selected = ref("");
```

You can now do all the obvious stuff with multiple select etc and anything else you might want.

Answer (score 1):

You can add `v-list-item` in a loop. On `<v-list-item>` add `@click` handler to update `selection` data. Try this:

```
<template>
  <v-app>
    <v-main>
      <v-card>
        <v-list>
          <v-list-item
            v-for="(item, index) in items"
            :key="index"
            @click="selection = index"
          >
            <v-list-item-title>{{ item.title }}</v-list-item-title>
          </v-list-item>
        </v-list>
      </v-card>
      <v-card class="mt-5">
        {{ selection }}
      </v-card>
    </v-main>
  </v-app>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data: () => ({
    selection: 0,
    items: [
      { title: "Item 0", value: 0 },
      { title: "Item 1", value: 1 },
      { title: "Item 2", value: 2 },
    ],
  }),
};
</script>
```

Comment: Is it possible to make a change to the `selection` variable beeing reflected in a selection change in the ui? E.g. another button changes the selection.

And the v-model="selection" is no longer needed then, right?

The rest works - thank you very much!

Comment: Just update the section, you don't need v-model then.You can add button like this: `<v-btn @click="selection = 1"> Select 1 </v-btn>`

Comment: Yes but chaging selection is not reflected in the UI. If I understand correctly this is only oneway: Clicking an item sets the `selection` variable but changing the variable does not viasually select an item in them list, right? V-Model seems to do nothing there.

Comment: That's right. It is redundant here.

Comment: Okay finally found it: <v-list-item :active="index == selection" ...>. Then it works both ways.

Comment: Great! Your code should highlight the active item. I didn't get what you wanted at first.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use `v-model:selected`.  Took me a while to figure this one out myself, but this works for me

```js
<template>
  <v-app>
    <v-main>
      <v-card>
        <v-list v-model:selected='selection' :items='items'></v-list> 
        </v-card>
      <v-card class='mt-5'>
        {{ selection }} 
      </v-card>
    </v-main>
  </v-app>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data: () => ({
      selection: [1], // this is an array of selected items
      items: [
        { title: 'Item 0', value: 0 },
        { title: 'Item 1', value: 1 },
        { title: 'Item 2', value: 2 },
      ],
    }),
  }
</script>
```